# How to represent 0x12345678 in C#

Tags: c#

My question is how to defined "0x12345678" values in C#?
I have the values from C code (header files), but need to translate them to C#.

```
// C
#define PARAM_START_ENABLE 0x2b15d3fa 

//C#
public const uint PARAM_START_ENABLE = ???
```

Comment: And what happened when you tried to reuse the exact same value?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a basic concept found in the language specs of c#

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Exactly same way:

```
public const uint PARAM_START_ENABLE = 0x2b15d3fa;
```

In C# integer literals can be represented in decimal and hexadecimal forms - [specification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664674%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).

Comment: Thanks a lot! Did not know I could do that.